Loading Firebase Config dynamically in Angular in @angular/fire
I have an angular v18 application with @angular/fire v18
I am using the modular api version of it. I am trying to load the firebase config dynamically during run time
Current I have the following code.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)), //load the firebaseConfig from an external file dynamically example from assets folder
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const providedFirestore = initializeFirestore(getApp(), {}, dbName);
      return providedFirestore;
    }),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}


I have services which inject angular/fire/auth and angular/fire/firestore, which are causing error when I am trying to load the conifg during run time.
Attached a link to chatgpt conversations, for what I have tried:
https://chatgpt.com/share/4674b197-1a89-467d-bab0-5b8f254b8b72
None of the options given by it worked.

And the error is what, exactly?  Please edit the question to show the error message and the line of code that causes it.  There should be enough information in your post so that anyone can copy it and reproduce the problem.

I found a way of pulling the configuration even before the App Module is executed in the main.ts file.
fetch('./assets/config.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(config => {
    environment.firebaseConfig = config;
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not load configuration', err));

And then using the loaded config in the app.module.ts as normal.
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const app = getApp(); // Get the app instance
      const db = initializeFirestore(app, {}, dbName); // Replace 'dbName' with your database name
      return db;
    }),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
  ],

